# MongDB memory consumption goes higher than value set in wiredTigercacheSizeGB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

**Hello experts**

I have a mongodb server running on my 2GB ec2 instance using following command

mongod --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=0.5

Below is my memory usage:

```
------------------------------------------------
MALLOC:      509658616 (  486.0 MiB) Bytes in use by application
MALLOC: +    100265984 (   95.6 MiB) Bytes in page heap freelist
MALLOC: +     10784344 (   10.3 MiB) Bytes in central cache freelist
MALLOC: +      8235328 (    7.9 MiB) Bytes in transfer cache freelist
MALLOC: +      3289712 (    3.1 MiB) Bytes in thread cache freelists
MALLOC: +      4063232 (    3.9 MiB) Bytes in malloc metadata
MALLOC:   ------------
MALLOC: =    636297216 (  606.8 MiB) Actual memory used (physical + swap)
MALLOC: +       385024 (    0.4 MiB) Bytes released to OS (aka unmapped)
MALLOC:   ------------
MALLOC: =    636682240 (  607.2 MiB) Virtual address space used
MALLOC:
MALLOC:          23555              Spans in use
MALLOC:             26              Thread heaps in use
MALLOC:           4096              Tcmalloc page size
------------------------------------------------
```

As per my understanding **Virtual address space used** is Total memory occupied by Mongodb.
It would great help if anyone can tell me why it is increasing above the Limit set which is 0.5(500MB)

```
----------------More  Info--------------------
{
    "name" : "wiredTiger",
    "supportsCommittedReads" : true,
    "oldestRequiredTimestampForCrashRecovery" : Timestamp(0, 0),
    "supportsPendingDrops" : true,
    "dropPendingIdents" : NumberLong(0),
    "supportsSnapshotReadConcern" : true,
    "readOnly" : false,
    "persistent" : true,
    "backupCursorOpen" : false
}

{
    "db" : "Database",
    "collections" : 43,
    "views" : 0,
    "objects" : 2780441,
    "avgObjSize" : 2756.87204116182,
    "dataSize" : 7665320055.0,
    "storageSize" : 2320449536.0,
    "numExtents" : 0,
    "indexes" : 58,
    "indexSize" : 156573696.0,
    "scaleFactor" : 1.0,
    "fsUsedSize" : 77780537344.0,
    "fsTotalSize" : 214746263552.0,
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

MongDB memory consumption goes higher than set value in wiredTigercacheSizeGB

Answer (score 1):

Wired tiger is a component of MongoDB. There are many other components. It is expected that memory usage for the entire server would be greater than the limit imposed on one aspect of one component of the server.